# Load XML in table

Tags: sql, oracle, xml-parsing

I do have the following data:

```
<EXDATA>
   <FLAG_LIST>
      <FLAG>
         <INST>APPLE</INST>
         <IDENT_LIST>
            <IDET NAME="ID_NUMBER" INST="AMOZ">111111111111</IDET>
            <IDET NAME="ID_PASSPORT" INST="AMOZ">2222222222222</IDET>
         </IDENT_LIST>
         <FLAGYN>0</FLAGYN>
         <EDATA_LIST_REQ>
            <EDATA NAME="NAM">JACKIE</EDATA>
            <EDATA NAME="SURNAME" INSTO="AMOZ">JOHN</EDATA>
         </EDATA_LIST_REQ>
      </FLAG>
       </FLAG_LIST>
</EXDATA>
```

I try to insert the data into a table with:

```
select x1.ID_NUMBER,X1.ID_PASSPORT,X2.NAM,x2.SURNAME
   from xml_tab t
      , xmltable(
          '/EXDATA/FLAG_LIST/FLAG/IDENT_LIST' 
          passing t.xml_data
          columns  ID_NUMBER varchar2(100) path 'IDET[1]/text()', 
         ID_PASSPORT number path 'IDET[2]/text()'
               , EDATA_LIST_REQ      xmltype      path 'EDATA_LIST_REQ' 
       ) (+) x1
      , xmltable(
          '/EDATA_LIST_REQ' 
         passing x1.EDATA_LIST_REQ
         columns 
         NAM   VARCHAR2(13) path 'EDATA[1]/text()' ,
           SURNAME VARCHAR2(50) path 'EDATA[2]/text()'
      ) (+) x2
```

But get no correct result:

```
ID_NUMBER   ID_PASSPORT    NAME   SURNAME 
111111111   222222222222   NULL    NULL
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your first XMLTable call you are looking for `EDATA_LIST_REQ` to pass down to the second XMLTable call. But you are looking for it under `/EXDATA/FLAG_LIST/FLAG/IDENT_LIST`. It isn't a child of `IDENT_LIST`, it's a sibling. So you could either change the path to traverse back up using `'./../EDATA_LIST_REQ'`:

```
select x1.ID_NUMBER,X1.ID_PASSPORT,X2.NAM,x2.SURNAME
   from xml_tab t
      , xmltable(
          '/EXDATA/FLAG_LIST/FLAG/IDENT_LIST' 
          passing t.xml_data
          columns  ID_NUMBER varchar2(100) path 'IDET[1]/text()', 
         ID_PASSPORT number path 'IDET[2]/text()'
               , EDATA_LIST_REQ      xmltype      path './../EDATA_LIST_REQ' 
       ) (+) x1
      , xmltable(
          '/EDATA_LIST_REQ' 
         passing x1.EDATA_LIST_REQ
         columns 
         NAM   VARCHAR2(13) path 'EDATA[1]/text()' ,
           SURNAME VARCHAR2(50) path 'EDATA[2]/text()'
      ) (+) x2
```

or leave that path and change the other two and the main XPath:

```
select x1.ID_NUMBER,X1.ID_PASSPORT,X2.NAM,x2.SURNAME
   from xml_tab t
      , xmltable(
          '/EXDATA/FLAG_LIST/FLAG' 
          passing t.xml_data
          columns  ID_NUMBER varchar2(100) path 'IDENT_LIST/IDET[1]/text()', 
         ID_PASSPORT number path 'IDENT_LIST/IDET[2]/text()'
               , EDATA_LIST_REQ      xmltype      path 'EDATA_LIST_REQ' 
       ) (+) x1
      , xmltable(
          '/EDATA_LIST_REQ' 
         passing x1.EDATA_LIST_REQ
         columns 
         NAM   VARCHAR2(13) path 'EDATA[1]/text()' ,
           SURNAME VARCHAR2(50) path 'EDATA[2]/text()'
      ) (+) x2
```

But you don't need outer joins, and don't need to explicitly refer to `/text()` when using XMLTable; but more problematic is your use of `[1]` and `[2]` to refer to specific nodes within a list. That seems to be making assumptions about the data structure which probably aren't guaranteed to always be true. It would be safer, and clearer, to use the attribute names since you have those. So I'd probably do something more like:

```
select x1.id_number, x1.id_passport, x2.nam, x2.surname
from xml_tab t
cross join xmltable (
  '/EXDATA/FLAG_LIST/FLAG' 
  passing t.xml_data
  columns id_number varchar2(100) path 'IDENT_LIST/IDET[@NAME="ID_NUMBER"]', 
          id_passport number      path 'IDENT_LIST/IDET[@NAME="ID_PASSPORT"]',
          edata_list_req xmltype  path 'EDATA_LIST_REQ' 
) x1
cross join xmltable (
  '/EDATA_LIST_REQ' 
  passing x1.edata_list_req
  columns nam varchar2(13)     path 'EDATA[@NAME="NAM"]',
          surname varchar2(50) path 'EDATA[@NAME="SURNAME"]'
) x2
```

Or even just `'.'` for the second XPath, though it doesn't hurt to repeat `/EDATA_LIST_REQ`.

You might want to check those data types though - is `id_number` actually a number, or alphanumeric? And are the lengths for the `varchar2` columns reasonable? Etc.